# HTML controls vertical align

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have input and 2 buttons placed in ont line in the table cell. I want to align it vertically bu control center. Also acceptable to make it the same height and its top and bottom borders should be at the one lines.

Actually buttons placed a bit lower that input.

HTML:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>save</button>
  <button>cancel</button>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
td input[type="text"]
{
  height: 18px
  margin: 0px
  padding: 0px
  border: none width: 50px;
}
td button
{
  height: 18px;
  ?????
}
```

Comment: Try `vertical-align:middle;` to input and buttons.

Comment: So you want an input element and then the two buttons below the input and everything centered vertically and centered?

Comment: @antejan: I tried it, not working.

Comment: @Leeish: Nope. Buttons should be at the same line and all 3 controls should be centered vertically.

Comment: Alex, can you provide live demo like jsfiddle? It is hard to help without working code.

Answer (score 1):

```
td input[type='text'], td button{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align will work in Inline-Block elements :

```
td{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean alignin elements verticaly than add this:

```
button, input { display:block; }
```

or if you want to verticaly aign the content inside them add this:

```
button, input { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
```